# Store data in BaseActivity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a `BaseActivity` and many other activities are extending from it. I want to store a specific variable (int or double for example) in `BaseActivity` then access it from all other extended activities. I'm aware of `SharedPrefrences` and `Intent`, but I really do need it like the way I asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make a `protected` variable and then assign a value to it. Then you will be able to retrieve value in classes which extended your `BaseActivity`